# IteratorProtocol needing next() function for generic linked list

Tags: swift, linked-list

I am trying to go through [99 Swift Problems](http://www.enekoalonso.com/projects/99-swift-problems/) and I getting stuck pretty early on, on problem 4. I have a linked list that I am trying to find the length of.

I was planning on iterating through the elements in the list to count them. But I can't iterate using a for/in loop without having it conform to Sequence and IteratorProtocol. I am getting stuck on the required next() function. I am not sure how to implement the next function in this case and I would love some direction.

Here is what I have for my linked list:

```html
public class List<T>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    public typealias Element = T
    
    var value: T!
    var nextItem: List<T>?
    
    public convenience init!(_ values: T...) {
        self.init(Array(values))
    }
    
    init!(_ values: Array<T>) {
        var values2 = values
        if values2.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        value = values2.removeFirst()
        nextItem = List(values2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to implement `IteratorProtocol` or `next`. You just want to implement `Sequence` in order to use `for/in`. The best way to implement `Sequence` for this type is by implementing `makeIterator`:

```
extension List: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<T> {
        var current: List<T>? = self
        return AnyIterator {
            let result = current?.value
            current = current?.nextItem
            return result
        }
    }
}

let list = List(1,2,3)!
for x in list { print(x) }  // 1 2 3
```